# Converting one pdb command to another, but it's not working

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, cpython

Need help, I am trying to add a change the functionality of `c command` to `quit` command, these changes are needed for further creation of new commands. I don't what I am doing wrong, how these two things are different first one is working fine but second one is not , I am just changing the behaviour

```
db = pdb.Pdb()
db.do_c = db.do_quit
no = 3
db.runcall(fun,no)
```

But this is not working  , in this case self.do_quit is not getting even called.

```
class dbg(pdb.Pdb):
    def custom_quit(self,arg):
        self.do_quit
db = dbg()
no = 3
db.do_c = db.custom_quit
db.runcall(fun,no)
```

I am just running on simple function fun

```
def fun(no):
    print("a")
    print("b")
    for i in range(0,no):
        print(i)
    return 'abc'
```

on command `c` it does nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to extend a method in a class is to use the same name
for the method (that is override it) while calling  `super()` to preserve
original method functionality:

So you can change your custom method to

```
class dbg(pdb.Pdb):
    def do_quit(self, arg):
        super().do_quit(arg)
        print('do something else')
        return(1)
```

and monkey patch it with:

```
db.do_c = db.do_quit # do_quit as usual
```

Take a look into `pdb.py` and search for the `do_quit` function and you'll
understand something is done that you have to do, or somehow preserve,
including `return(1)`